# XML reading is not working in my ASP CLASSIC code - Load file returns FALSE

Tags: xml, vba, asp-classic, outlook

In my outlook 2013 I created a function that saves the sender, subject and domain name in variables. These variables are then transferred/created into an XML file which all works.

Though the next thing I want to achieve is to read the XML files variables and use them on my web page. The reading however does not work, it returns nothing.

The Outlook 2013 macro creates the XML file on a server, and it also ends up there (checked it). 
The ASP file is located on the same server of the XML file in the same folder.

My code is as follows:

**The XML file that is created (with a xml extension)**

```
<Mail2Memo>
    <Receiver>Nicolas</Receiver>
    <Domain>hotmail.com</Domain>
    <Subject>I am awesome</Subject>
</Mail2Memo>
```

**The ASP code that should read, and output the XML values. (did the output in a table for now)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <TITLE>Send mails</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>  

    <%

        Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmlDOM.async = False
        xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
        xmlDOM.Load("MyXMLFile.xml")

        Test =  xmlDOM.Load("MyXMLFile.xml")
        response.write (Test)

        Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("Mail2Memo")

        For Each itemAttrib In itemList
           newReceiver =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("Receiver").text
           newDomain =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("Domain").text
           newSubject =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("Subject").text
           %>
           <tr>
              <td><%=newReceiver%></td>
              <td><%=newDomain%></td>
              <td><%=newSubject%></td>
           </tr>
        <%
        Next

        Set xmlDOM = Nothing
        Set itemList = Nothing

    %>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This code just returns an empty web page for some reason.. 
The test variable that I have build in (to see what goes wrong) returns the value FALSE, so I am guessing the XML file isn't picked up?

By the way, in the Outlook VBA I added the `Microsoft XML, 3.0` as reference

Anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE XML Generating Code**

The code below is being executed in outlook itself.

```
'----------------------------------------------------'
'-----------------WRITE TO XML FILE------------------'
'----------------------------------------------------'

Dim objDom As DOMDocument
Dim objXMLRootelement As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objXMLelement As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objXMLattr As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim objMemberElem As IXMLDOMElement

Set objDom = New DOMDocument

'~~> Creates root element
Set objXMLRootelement = objDom.createElement("Mail2Memo")
objDom.appendChild objXMLRootelement

'~~> Create Melder element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Melder")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = MelderNaam

'~~> Create Bedrijf element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Bedrijf")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = MelderDomein

'~~> Creates Onderwerp element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Onderwerp")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Onderwerp

'~~> Creates Omschrijving element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Omschrijving")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Omschrijving

'~~> Creates Datum element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Datum")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = OntvangstDatum

'~~> Creates Ontvanger element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Receiver")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Receiver

'~~> Creates EindDatum element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("EindDatum")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = EindDatum

'~~> Creates Status element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Status")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Status

'~~> Creates Debiteur element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Debiteur")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Debiteur

'~~> Creates Soort element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Soort")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Soort

'~~> Creates Becode element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("Becode")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = Becode

'~~> Creates Email element
Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("MelderEmail")
objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
objXMLelement.Text = MelderEmail

'~~> Saves XML data to a file
Select Case Receiver
Case "DAVE"
    objDom.Save ("\\SERVERADRESS\DaveMailFile.xml")
Case "RICHARD"
    objDom.Save ("\\SERVERADRESS\RichardMailFile.xml")
Case "NICK"
    objDom.Save ("\\SERVERADRESS\NickMailFile.xml")

End Select
```

Comment: If you're making a `ServerHTTPRequest` you need to specify the full url of your xml file - ie `xmlDOM.Load("http://path-to/MyXMLFile.xml")`.

Comment: Ok very stupid of me I looked over this.. Got it working now! Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling the Outlook macro? Are you calling it from a web page?

Comment: Nope, the outlook macro is being called from outlook itself (a function which is triggered in the outlook ribbon). The user presses in outlook the button and the variables are being generated in outlook through the VBA code. The XML is also being generated in the VBA. The XML file that is created will be saved on the server. For a better understanding I Uploaded the VBA code in outlook for the XML generating.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Set xmlDOM  = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
xmlDOM.async = false
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True

' DO NOT validate XML
xmlDOM.validateOnParse = false 


'xmlDOM.preserveWhiteSpace = false ' if you want to remove spaces
Test = xmlDOM.Load("MyXMLFile.xml")

If Not Test Then
  Response.write "File is empty" 'check the path
Else
  set itemList = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("Mail2Memo")

  For Each objNode In objNodeList
  '...
  Next
End if
```

Note the part

```
xmlDOM.validateOnParse = false
```

to understand if the problem is about the XML file format.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't automate Outlook on the server from any unattended application or service.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about this in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: He is not automating it from the web page.

Comment: @JohnSaunders , I see the following text in the initial post: The Outlook 2013 macro creates the XML file on a server...

Comment: Yes, but how is the macro invoked? He says nothing about invoking them from the web page.

Comment: We don't know how the macro (Outlook) is run in the server. That's why I think your down vote is not applicable. Or do you know more than others?

Comment: No, but I try to find out. That's why I asked the OP in a comment before assuming he's invoking Interop from a server application. I have a canned comment I always use in those cases, and have not decided to use it in this case.